# Web Applications under Apache Tomcat with multiple directory contexts

Tags: configuration, tomcat, web-applications

I have two webapps, *prod-1.2.1.war* and *test-2.0.0.war*.

If I put these straight into the "tomcat/webapps"-folder, they'll get deployed as;

- hXXp://localhost/prod-1.2.1/
- hXXp://localhost/test-2.0.0/

This works but really I would like them to show up as;

- hXXp://localhost/vegshop/prod/
- hXXp://localhost/vegshop/test/

As you see I somehow would like the "vegshop" to be included in the context path.
I also would like the version-numbering to disappear without having to rename the WAR-files.

Thank you.

This is Apache Tomcat v6.0 under Linux 2.6, running SUN JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include the include the `/vegshop/` part in the URL like you want with Tomcat.  Webapps are not mere files that can be placed where ever one wants.   With Tomcat,  `/vegshop/` is either:

1. a discrete webapp
2. a folder under the `ROOT` webapp (the default, if there is no webapp.

The best you can do is something like be renaming your .war files.  E.g. `prod-1.2.1.war` to  `vegshop-prod.war`

- `http://localhost/vegshop/`
- `http://localhost/vegshop-test/`

If this `/vegshop/prod/` thing is really, really important to you, then the only option I would consider is to proxy Tomcat with a web server (like Apache httpd) and rewrite the URLs.  There might even be a way to code something wild with Tomcat, but all of this feels over the top for such a cosmetic change.  Is it really that important?